Total angle of deviation in a system of two prism
In my professor's slides, I saw that the total angle of deviation in a system of two prisms that are subtended by an angle of $\beta$ is given by:
$$\delta_{tot}=\sqrt{\delta_1^2+\delta_{2}^2+2\delta_{1}\delta_{2}cos(\beta)}$$
where $\delta_1$ represents the angle of deviation of the first prism and $\delta_2$ represents the angle of deviation due to the second prism. ($\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ are considered as vectors in this case) The angle of deviation depends upon the angle of incidence. But, I am uncertain about the angle of incidence for the second case. It can be either of the two below:

The angle the ray hits after emerging from the prism 1. In that case, the angle of incidence for the second prism will be a linear function of the angle of deviation of the first prism.
The angle of incidence of the first prism itself. That is, the angle of deviation for the angle of incidence $i$ (angle of incidence of the first prism in our case) is found separately for both prisms and assigned to $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$, respectively.

Or both can be wrong. What is the angle of incidence that corresponds to the $\delta_2$ in this case?

The angles of deviation in this case (under the first-order paraxial approximation) are all independent to the direction of the incident ray.

Under the first-order paraxial approximation, the derivative angle of each single thin-prism can be expressed as:
$$ 
\delta_1 = \alpha_1 (n_1-1) \quad\quad 
\delta_2 = \alpha_2 (n_2-1)
$$
where $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are the apex angles of the thin-prisms respectively, $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the refractive indexes.
Now place these two thin-prisms in a coaxial way, like this:

Then the total deviation angle caused by this prism-pair can be expressed with the deviation vectors (as you said). Using the coordinates of the above picture, we can draw the deviation vectors like below:

I believe that these pictures can answer your question well.

It'd be helpful if you can recommend me a resource that elaborates on this matter

Of course, okay. This paper Prism Scanner may be the earliest source of the formula that you're interested in. And, maybe this one will help a lot too: Analytic solution for double optical metasurface beam scanners
